# Hive tables meta details needed

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

```
select * from information_schema.columns;
```

In MySQL gives me the dbname, table name and column details of a MySQL db.

Can I get the same details in hive from any tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured your metastore in mysql .Then there are tables in the metastore database named DBS, COLUMNS_V2 which will have metadata of all hive DBs and tables .

Answer (score 0):

[Describe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Describe) will meet your requirement.

```
   hive -e "desc formatted tablename"
```

On above output you can use grep like below

```
hive -e "desc formatted tablename" |grep -i database
```

only column names can be get with below command.

```
hive -e "show columns from tablename"
```

Comment: Thanks Bala.
BUt actually I want to extract the data in this order dbname,table name, column name.

Comment: Hari,you know tablename.database name and column names can be get from above command,if you want only  those details  ,just grep them .