# Hive - getting the column names count of a table

Tags: hive, hql

How can I get the hive column count names using HQL? I know we can use the describe.tablename to get the names of columns. How do we get the count?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive, how do I retrieve all the database's tables columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239565/hive-how-do-i-retrieve-all-the-databases-tables-columns)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - definitly a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table mytable(i int,str string,dt date, ai array<int>,strct struct<k:int,j:int>);
```

---

```
select  count(*) 
from    (select transform ('') 
                using 'hive -e "desc mytable"' 
                as col_name,data_type,comment
        ) t
;
```

> 5

---

**Some additional playing around:**

```
create table mytable (id int,first_name string,last_name string);
insert into mytable values (1,'Dudu',null);

select size(array(*)) from mytable limit 1;
```

This is not bulletproof since not all combinations of columns types can be combined into an array.
It also requires that the table will contain at least 1 row.

---

**Here is a more complex but also stronger solution (types versa), but also requires that the table will contain at least 1 row**

```
select size(str_to_map(val)) from (select transform (struct(*)) using 'sed -r "s/.(.*)./\1/' as val from mytable) t;
```

Comment: I'll edit it later to support partitions. I also might be able to overcome the 1 row limitation with the STRUCT solution.